# How to save the changes?

Tags: database, vb.net, winforms, datagridview, save

In my code, all functions work well: save button, update and delete actually work but when I close the program and reopen it, all changes  disappear.
So, the `Save` button works when I open the program only; I want that when I change anything, it changes also in code.

By the way, the data is contained in a DataGridView.

```
Imports System.Data.DataTable

Public Class Form1
    Dim table As New DataTable("Table")
    Dim index As Integer

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        table.Columns.Add("ID", Type.GetType("System.Int32"))
        table.Columns.Add("First Name", Type.GetType("System.String"))
        table.Columns.Add("Last Name", Type.GetType("System.String"))
        table.Columns.Add("Age", Type.GetType("System.Int32"))
        table.Columns.Add("Programming", Type.GetType("System.Int32"))
        table.Columns.Add("Law", Type.GetType("System.Int32"))
        table.Columns.Add("English", Type.GetType("System.Int32"))
        table.Columns.Add("GPA", Type.GetType("System.Int32"))
        table.Columns.Add("Grade", Type.GetType("System.string"))

        table.Rows.Add(1, "XXXX", "YYYYY", 21, 88, 77, 90, 89)
        table.Rows.Add(2, "SSDD", "hGSQ", 33, 70, 96, 72, 82)
        table.Rows.Add(3, "fgfgd", "jgfdd", 53)
        table.Rows.Add(4, "cvfghyghj", "sdrgtyh", 19)
        table.Rows.Add(5, "hghfd", "ghjgdf", 36)
        table.Rows.Add(6, "cvvdfgh", "juyrfdvc", 63)
        table.Rows.Add(7, "aefht", "cvfhytrff", 21)
        table.Rows.Add(8, "wghyuj", "mihgdwrh", 33)
        table.Rows.Add(9, "qsztii", "bvdhjh", 53)
        table.Rows.Add(10, "rytyufd", "esdfzr", 19)

        DataGridView1.DataSource = table
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click
        Table.rows.Add(TextBoxID.Text, TextBoxFN.Text, TextBoxLN.Text, TextBoxAGE.Text)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = table
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox4_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBoxAGE.TextChanged

    End Sub

    Private Sub DataGridView1_CellContentClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellContentClick, DataGridView1.CellClick
        index = e.RowIndex
        Dim selectedRow As DataGridViewRow
        selectedRow = DataGridView1.Rows(index)
        TextBoxID.Text = selectedRow.Cells(0).Value.ToString()
        TextBoxFN.Text = selectedRow.Cells(1).Value.ToString()
        TextBoxLN.Text = selectedRow.Cells(2).Value.ToString()
        TextBoxAGE.Text = selectedRow.Cells(3).Value.ToString()
        TextBoxPro.Text = selectedRow.Cells(4).Value.ToString()
        TextBoxLaw.Text = selectedRow.Cells(5).Value.ToString()
        TextBoxENGL.Text = selectedRow.Cells(6).Value.ToString()
        TextBoxGPA.Text = selectedRow.Cells(7).Value.ToString()
        TextBoxGrade.Text = selectedRow.Cells(8).Value.ToString()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnUpdate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnUpdate.Click
        Dim newDataRow As DataGridViewRow

        newDataRow = DataGridView1.Rows(index)

        newDataRow.Cells(0).Value = TextBoxID.Text
        newDataRow.Cells(1).Value = TextBoxFN.Text
        newDataRow.Cells(2).Value = TextBoxLN.Text
        newDataRow.Cells(3).Value = TextBoxAGE.Text
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnDelete_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDelete.Click
        DataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(index)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: You need to permanently store your data somewhere. A database, a JSON, a CSV file. If you keep your data in memory, when you app closes, all is gone.

Comment: well my knowledge in database and sql is so bad can you give a hint how to store the data?

Comment: *"my knowledge in database and sql is so bad"*. Then you need to do some research and spend some time learning. It's not the purpose of this site to teach you things from scratch.

Comment: I think I've already done that. Research those subjects and make a specific question when you have one.

Comment: Hint: use ADO.net to connect to a database.